# Windows 10 IE INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows-10, dns, localhost, internet-explorer-11

I have Windows 10 and IE 11, when trying to browse https://localhost/ it gives me error:

*There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.*

*Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND*

Everything works fine on Chrome.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this：

1. run **Powershell** or **CMD** as administrator.
2. Type **ipconfig /all > C:\ipconfig.txt** to save your IP configuration in the txt
3. Then type, **netsh int ip reset**
4. Then type, **netsh winsock reset**
5. Reboot your PC and test.